# Jupyter notebook header, without number

Tags: formatting, markdown, jupyter

Before, when I wrote # Header [markdown]
jupyter would return a title with a more prominent font.
Now Jupyter returns the font prominent plus a number before it.

**Before:**

(hashtag) HEADER

Header (bigger)

**Now:**

(hashtag) HEADER

1 HEADER

Any idea how to remove 1 before the header? thanks

[markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2COE.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXGOo.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I found to solve this question is to use:
https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Once installed, it's possible, in the table of contents, ToC2 settings to remove automatically number headings, hope it helps.